# Is storing and accessing functions a good use-case for Enum?

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

I use Enum classes to explicitly show possible values of argument. It is nice and concise.

However, when I am accessing one Enum from another it stars to look unpythonic: `Functions[day.value].value`. The fact that I need to pass and retrieve the value attribute of Enum adds complexity.

How can this (fictional) code be rewritten to use only one Enum, and not need to access the `value` attribute?

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from enum import Enum


class Day(Enum):
    YESTERDAY = 'YESTERDAY'
    TODAY = 'TODAY'
    TOMORROW = 'TOMORROW'


def get_date(day: Day):
    class Functions(Enum):
        YESTERDAY = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=-1)
        TODAY = datetime.now()
        TOMORROW = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1)
    return Functions[day.value].value.date()


today = get_date(Day.TODAY)
yesterday = get_date(Day.YESTERDAY)
tomorrow = get_date(Day.TOMORROW)
```

Comment: I wouldn't use an enum for dynamic data like that, a regular class seems like a better fit...

Comment: Are you doing this to avoid if/else? In python you can also use a dict for it `return {Day.TODAY: datetime.now(), ...}.get(day)` which looks more pythonic to me. I am also worried a bit that the time/place of declaration of `Functions` enum affects its values... but that might just be me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you are trying to implement a `switch` statement that python does not have. The most common way I have seen being used to do such a thing is via a `dict`:

```
def get_date(day: Day):
    return {
        Day.YESTERDAY: datetime.now() + timedelta(days=-1),
        Day.TODAY: datetime.now(),
        Day.TOMORROW: datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1),
    }[day].date()
```

Note that I am accessing `[day]` directly which might raise KeyError. If you want to avoid this, you can use `get(day, default=datetime.now())` which essentially attempts to access the key and if does not exist it returns `datetime.now()`.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible for an Enum to have other attributes besides `name` and `value` -- for example, `date`:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
from enum import Enum

class Day(Enum):
    YESTERDAY = 'YESTERDAY'
    TODAY = 'TODAY'
    TOMORROW = 'TOMORROW'
    #
    @property
    def date(self):
        today = date.today()
        return {
                'YESTERDAY': today + timedelta(days=-1),
                'TODAY': today,
                'TOMORROW': today + timedelta(days=1),
                }[self.value]
```

and in use:

```
>>> Day.YESTERDAY
<Day.YESTERDAY: 'YESTERDAY'>

>>> Day.YESTERDAY.date
datetime.date(2020, 11, 9)

>>> Day.TODAY
<Day.TODAY: 'TODAY'>

>>> Day.TODAY.date
datetime.date(2020, 11, 10)

>>> Day.TOMORROW
<Day.TOMORROW: 'TOMORROW'>

>>> Day.TOMORROW.date
datetime.date(2020, 11, 11)
```

---

Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.